# Run elevated Powershell Script and import system modules

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, batch-file

I'm trying to call a .PS1 using a batch file to produce a csv file with just the User Name and Other Telephone number details. I have the script to produce the csv file.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties otherTelephone | 
    select name, @{L='otherTelephone'; E={$_.otherTelephone[0]}} | sort-object otherTelephone | select-object -last 1000 | 
    Export-Csv C:\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

and I have the batch file to elevate the PowerShell

```
powershell -noprofile -command "&{ start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -file C:\Test.ps1' -verb RunAs}"
```

The problem is when I try to import the system modules by adding

```
powershell.exe -ImportSystemModules
```

to the front of the powershell script, the CSV only returns the header information e.g. name and otherTelephone. The script works if I import the modules manually i.e right click import system modules, but not when I try to load modules before running the script.

Basically I need to run the PS script as admin, import the system modules and have the code output my data.

Any help as to where I am going wrong is appreciated.

```
powershell.exe -ImportSystemModules Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties otherTelephone | 
    select name, @{L='otherTelephone'; E={$_.otherTelephone[0]}} | sort-object otherTelephone | select-object -last 10 | 
    Export-Csv C:\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to load the modules inside your script use the following code:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "$PSHOME*"} | Import-Module
```

The `-ImportSystemModules` switch is a flag for `powershell.exe`. If you call `powershell.exe -ImportSystemModules` inside of your script it will start another powershell instance and load the modules inside of it.

You could also add the `-ImportSystemModules` to your powershell call inside the batch file. That should work too

Regards

Comment: Great help thanks, I added the -ImportSystemModules to the batch file and ran it that way      **powershell -noprofile -command "&{ start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-importSystemModules -file C:\VMRs\1.ps1' -verb RunAs}"**